# How do the big protocols deploy their smart contacts?

Tags: contract-deployment

I wanted to know the production-level practice for deploying contracts. Is it the same way we deploy via hardhat or is there any other method big protocols use? Any github repos would help.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of alternatives.

In the tooling section, there are at least:

1. Typical hardhat
2. https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy
3. All sorts of stuff for Foundry - not too familiar with these

One of the questions one needs to ask before deployments is whether they want to have the same address on all networks or not. The benefit is that it's easier for everyone to manage, and the downside is that it's more complicated to accomplish and possibly introduces security issues.

Comment: So it simply means, it's similar to what we normally do in the testnets, Like storing the private key in an env file and then running a hardhat script etc.

Comment: at least with foundry there are better ways to manage private keys. but anyway, yes, scripts. unsure if there are some services for deployment management.